# Change slideRight to SlideDown in JQuery.mmenu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mmenu

I have a menu with [jquery.mmenu plugin](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) but I need change the effect from `slideRight` to `slideDown` in order to make it into a dropdown.

How can I make this change?

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page - http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/playground.html. In extensions, under change the position of the menu, change the selection and you can copy the code from the bottom of *that* page.

Here is the relevant section

```
$("#menu").mmenu({
    "offCanvas": {
        "position": "top"
    }
});
```